# AWS Cognito linking user accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When user bob@example.com logs in via. user-pool (where email is username alias) he get's cognito-id-a, if he logs in via. google he gets cognito-id-b

But to link these 2 ids I understand from the document that the api has to be invoked by supplying both the login token as part of the request. But for both the logins to co-exists the user should log-in on both the providers at the same time (i.e one after the other in the same session). Could someone explain the step-by-step flow of how this could be achieved.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, at one point they do have to be used together for some identity. After that first call with both tokens, using any one token linked to that identity is sufficient. The Cognito [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html) has more details on the flow, if needed.

As far as examples, the Cognito [sample apps](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo) on GitHub would be a useful starting point. Each sample supports logging in with multiple providers.